# Comparing direct and indirect effects between mediation models with different IVs

Tags: mediation

I'm running a few simple mediation models with differing IVs, but the same M and DV.

IV_1 = race (0 = white, 1 = minority)

IV_2 = racial dissimilarity (continuous variable)

M = engagement (continuous variable)

DV = turnover (binary; 0 = did not turnover, 1 = did turnover)

**How can I compare the direct and indirect effects of the models?**

For instance, let's say in model 1: IV_1 > M > DV, the direct effect of race on engagement is .17 (p <.001).

In model 2: IV_2 > M > DV, the direct effect of racial dissimilarity on engagement is .48 (p < .001).

Should I do a bootstrap t-test similar to when you compare means of two samples? Or is there another way to compare the direct effects? Examine overall model fit of each?

**Similarly, how can I compare the indirect effects of the models?**

Let's say in model 1: IV_1 > M > DV, the significant indirect effect = -.07

In model 2: IV_2 > M > DV, the significant indirect effect = -.16.

Since the DV is binary, is it as simple as comparing the odds ratios? Or do need to do some sort of bootstrapped hypothesis test on the difference? Or is it comparing overall model fit (though this wouldn't parse apart direct and indirect effects...maybe doing so isn't needed...?)?

Part of the paper's hypothesis is that racial dissimilarity is a more impactful way of conceptualizing diversity, as opposed to categorical race, which is why I'm looking to compare the direct and indirect effects of the model.